# How Can I Create an 8 by 2 Column That Has All Repeated Values and Places Sorted Into 1 Group?

Tags: r, rstudio

So I made an Excel file to keep track of spending my dining dollars throughout 1 semester. In it has dates, where I bought something, what I bought, and how much it cost.

I want to create a bar graph in RStudio of how much I spent for the semester for all locations.

Problem: I want to create a 8x2 table. One column would have the location of each place and the other would be total money spent there.

I made a variable that is a vector of all the places I went throughout the semester (which is 8). I also made a data frame that has location and cost. However, I went to each place multiple times throughout the semester.

I tried using the table function on the data frame but what I got was an 8x3 table, with the 3rd column being frequency.

```r
Location_Vector <- c("Cha-Time", "Cocina Fresca", "Delancey's", "Emporium", "Jasmine", "SAC","Starbucks", "WCS") 

#vector that will be used as the labels for the horizontial axis of the graph


DD_DF<- data.frame(Location_DF, Dining_Dollars = Spending_Dining_Dollars$Cost)
DD_DF #shows where I spent my dining dollars and how much for all transactions
```

Comment: What's in the ```Spending_Dining_Dollars``` data.frame? If you have the location in that data.frame, you can use ```dplyr::group_by(Spending_Dining_Dollars, Location)%>%dplyr::summarize(sum(Cost))``` or base ```aggregate()``` or data.table ```dt[, sum(Cost), by = 'Location')```. There's just not enough to work off of now.

Comment: You could use `library(dplyr); DD_DF %>% count(Location_DF, wt = Dining_Dollars)`

Answer (score 3):

Good question @Iftiar.

In the future, can you please include a snippet of the raw data? It would be very helpful.

For this, you're looking for an aggregation of your raw data. The suggestion given by @Cole is the solution that will work for you. You'll need to group your data together (`dplyr::group_by()`), then aggregate the result (`dplyr::summarise()`).

To prove the results, the below script generates the raw data based of random sampling (`base::sample()`).

```
# Load Packages
library(dplyr)   #For creating chains of functions
library(english) #For converting numbers to words
library(stringi) #For converting words to Proper case
library(ggplot2) #For plotting the result

# Generate raw data
Date <- seq(as.Date("2019/08/01"), as.Date("2019/08/30"), by="days") %>% 
    sample(size=100, replace=TRUE) %>% 
    sort()

Location <- c("Cha-Time", "Cocina Fresca", "Delanceys", "Emporium",
              "Jasmine", "SAC","Starbucks", "WCS") %>% 
    sample(size=100, replace=TRUE)

Food <- seq(1, 10) %>% 
    as.english() %>% 
    stri_trans_general(id="Title") %>% 
    paste("Food", .) %>%
    sample(size=100, replace=TRUE)

Cost <- seq(1, 20, by=0.5) %>% 
    sample(size=100, replace=TRUE)

Spending_Dining_Dollars <- data.frame(Date, Location, Food, Cost)

print(head(Spending_Dining_Dollars))
          Date  Location       Food Cost
[1] 2019-08-01 Delanceys   Food Six 13.5
[2] 2019-08-01  Emporium  Food Five 12.5
[3] 2019-08-01 Delanceys Food Three 12.0
[4] 2019-08-02 Delanceys Food Three 14.5
[5] 2019-08-02   Jasmine Food Three 15.5
[6] 2019-08-02 Starbucks  Food Nine  2.5
```

Then, you can group it together and summarise the result like this.

```
# Generate aggregate data.frame
DD_DF <- Spending_Dining_Dollars %>% 
    group_by(Location) %>% 
    summarise(Amount=sum(Cost))

# Prove dimensions are correct
print(dim(DD_DF))
[1] 8 2
```

We know this is correct because the dimensions are the same as you originally requested (`base::dim()`).

Lastly, you're looking for a plot to display the results? This can be done using a column plot (`ggplot2::geom_col()`) using the aggregated data frame.

```
# Plot the result
DD_Plot <- DD_DF %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Location, Amount)) +
    geom_col()
print(DD_Plot)
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image: Column Plot of the Aggregate data.frame]

I trust that helps you with your question.